# How to upscale final render (compositing)

Tags: rendering, blender-internal-render-engine, compositing-nodes, pixel-art

I am working on retro style graphics. How do I upscale my final render through compositor?

I'm rendering frames with 480x270 resolution and want to upscale it to 1920x1080 without interpolation (or with nearest neighbour).

I found a topic which suggested rendering 1920x1080, pixelate to 480x270 and then upscale to 1920x1080. This method is not suitable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know a way to do this without saving out your render as an image first. Basically, you'll render your image at 480 x 270 as normal, and save as an image. Then bring the render into the compositor; use the transform node with the "Nearest" setting from the dropdown menu; and for scale, just scale it enough to match the new resolution (480 x 270 to 1920 x 1080 is a scale value of 4).

[image]

Comment: Many thanks, mate! It works!

Comment: How can I do a scale of 3 from an image that is already 1920 x 1080. When I try this method it won't allow me to save an image from it. It is grayed out from saving Ny i.